# Audio is deactivated after each reboot on Yosemite

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, sound-volume

After clean installing Yosemite and rebooting my MacBook Pro, audio seems to be deactivated, although the sound is active and I can use it. But I can't change the volume. The icon in the menu bar is grayed out:

[image]

If I run

```
sudo killall coreaudiod
```

in the terminal, it is activated and I can use it as usual again.

What could cause the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a [NVRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) and [SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) reset?

Comment: Yes, no luck. I even tried another clean install. Same problem.